# anaconda prompt shows No module named 'tensorflow'

Tags: python, anaconda

i can use tensorflow in spyder and in jupyter but cannot anaconda prompt simply displays No module named 'tensorflow'

when i enter `pip show tensorflow` it gives me the tensorflow version as 2.1.0 in the prompt itself but while running a file throws the above error message

Comment: have you tried installing tensorflow within your anaconda environment?

Comment: I think anaconda has its own area for installed modules, that is not shared with spyder.  Check your anaconda manual and follow the procedure for installing modules.